# How does Spring work with apparently no code?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to understand the [example described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html).

What is puzzling to me is that there is apparently no code. I run the `spring-security-samples-insecuremvc-3.2.x` within Tomcat and a form is presented to interact with but there is no Java code whatsoever as far as I can see. I can't even find the form. I realize that the code must be in one of the dependencies but I am baffled at how this all works.

Answer (score 1):

Spring does *generate/provide* a default login form if it's configured to do form-based login and no custom login form is configured.

Sidenote: how to create and configure a custom login form is, for example, explained here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html (to long to be copy/pasted here).

Comment: Thanks, Marcel: So even without code, a dynamic web project (in Eclipse) that is run in Tomcat will generate a login form. But at this point I do not see where the configuration to do the form-based login is done: the insecuremvc project seems to have nothing other than pom.xml that I can see. I will look further.

Comment: There's more than just the POM, see e.g. `src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/config/SecurityConfig.java`. However, even that is minimal, a lot is "magic" - welcome to the world of Spring (Security) :). To fully understand what's happing you need to read up on what `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` and the super class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` provide out-of-the-box.

Comment: But the example lacks any Java classes whatsoever.

Comment: Obviously not...I told you where they are. There's a link to the examples in your post, I downloaded & extracted the ZIP referenced there and started digging through the artifacts it contains. Over and out.

Comment: We are talking about two different examples. Insecuremvc has no java classes. I am looking at it in Eclipse right now.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at this sample today with the same questions as you - where the heck is the source?  I finally found the answer I think you're looking for.  Take a look at the pom.xml and in the dependencies you'll see spring-security-samples-messages-jc. Assuming you downloaded all the samples, import that project into STS and you'll find the files you're looking for.

BTW, I've been following the instructions on the spring security website to add security to this sample and I have not yet been able to get it to work - the login screen does not appear. Let me know if you have better luck than me.

Comment: Just to clarify - I downloaded the spring-security-4.0.2.RELEASE zip as well as the spring-security-master from github, but I would guess that 3.2.x would be set up the same with the source code in the messages-jc project.

Comment: Got it to work. Stupid mistake with files in the scr/test/java dir instead of src/main/java.

Answer (score 0):

The default spring security login form is generated by the class [`org.springframework.security.web.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.html) which is in `spring-security-web-$version.jar`

The method is [`generateLoginPageHtml()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/xref/org/springframework/security/ui/webapp/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.html)